# unable to run test cases in IE browser in protractor, selenium framework for angular.js web application

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, test-strategy, angular

I was trying to execute test cases in `IE`, and  I'm facing errors as shown in error picture, my config file is shown below.

Using `IE 11.09` with `Selenium WebDriver-4.0.0` in `Windows Server 2012 R2` standard version.

Please help me how to work on this issue.

[image: Error picture]
[image: config file]

Comment: I am unable to start webdriver session,i have tried updating webdriver using webdriver-manager update -ie

Answer (score 0):

Just set the browser level to 100% it should be fixed.
Zoom level for your browser is set to 150% which might someone has set manually but it is required to be 100% to make it work correctly.

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how/why the browser zoom setting changes to 150%.